# How can i change the format of the date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, indexing

```
elif s[0] == 'FindTrend':
        stocx = [item[0] for item in stocklist]
        stocx1 = [item[1] for item in stocklist]

        stocxx = [item[0] for item in stocklist1]
        stocxx1 = [item[1] for item in stocklist1]

        dat1 = s[2].split('-')
        year3 = dat1[0]
        month3 = dat1[1].lstrip('0')
        day3 = dat1[2].lstrip('0')
        datt2 = month3+'/'+day3+'/'+year3
        
        dat2 = s[3].split('-')
        year4 = dat2[0]
        month4 = dat2[1].lstrip('0')
        day4 = dat2[2].lstrip('0')
        datt3 = month4+'/'+day4+'/'+year4
```

how do i change the output of this to become the format like "YYYY-MM-DD"  (ex:2019-07-06)

I tried arranging it differently but im stuck

here is the full line of code for anyone that's willing to help :)

```py
from collections import namedtuple
stoc = namedtuple('stoc','date close')
def StockMarket():
    'This function reads two stock files, PFE and MRNA, it then is able to find the price on a specific date and the maxpossible profit and loss, as well as the morning and evening star trends.'
    stocks = {}
    stocks1 = {}
    stocklist = []
    stocklist1 = []
    dates = []
    while True:
        s = input('$ ').split()
        if s[0] == 'quit':
            return
        elif s[0] == 'ReadFiles':
            for entry in open(s[1],'r'):
                elist = entry.split(',')
                stocks[elist[0]] = elist[4]
                readfiles = stoc(elist[0], elist[4])
                stocklist.append(readfiles)
            for entry1 in open(s[2],'r'):
                elist1 = entry1.split(',')
                stocks1[elist1[0]] = elist1[4]
                readfiles1 = stoc(elist1[0], elist1[4])
                stocklist1.append(readfiles1)
        elif s[0] == 'PricesOnDate':
            dates = s[1].split('-')
            year = dates[0]
            month = dates[1].lstrip('0')
            day = dates[2].lstrip('0')
            date1 = month+'/'+day+'/'+year
            print('PFE:', stocks[date1], '|', 'MRNA:', stocks1[date1])
        elif s[0] == 'MaxPossible':
            sto = [item[0] for item in stocklist]
            sto1 = [item[1] for item in stocklist]

            st = [item[0] for item in stocklist1]
            st1 = [item[1] for item in stocklist1]
            
            dates1 = s[3].split('-')
            year1 = dates1[0]
            month1 = dates1[1].lstrip('0')
            day1 = dates1[2].lstrip('0')
            date2 = month1+'/'+day1+'/'+year1
            
            dates2 = s[4].split('-')
            year2 = dates2[0]
            month2 = dates2[1].lstrip('0')
            day2 = dates2[2].lstrip('0')
            date3 = month2+'/'+day2+'/'+year2


            if s[1] == 'profit':
                if s[2] == 'PFE':
                    stocksub_list = sto1[sto.index(date2):sto.index(date3)+1]
                    for i in range(0, len(stocksub_list)):
                        stocksub_list[i] = float(stocksub_list[i])
                    a = max(stocksub_list)
                    price = stocksub_list[0]
                    b = min(stocksub_list[stocksub_list.index(price):stocksub_list.index(max(stocksub_list))+1])
                    print(a-b)

                if s[2] == 'MRNA':
                    stocksub_list1 = st1[st.index(date2):st.index(date3)+1]
                    for i in range(0, len(stocksub_list1)):
                        stocksub_list1[i] = float(stocksub_list1[i])
                    a1 = max(stocksub_list1)
                    price1 = stocksub_list1[0]
                    b1 = min(stocksub_list1[stocksub_list1.index(price1):stocksub_list1.index(max(stocksub_list1))+1])
                    print(a1-b1)

            if s[1] == 'loss':
                if s[2] == 'PFE':
                    stocksub_list = sto1[sto.index(date2):sto.index(date3)+1]
                    for i in range(0, len(stocksub_list)):
                        stocksub_list[i] = float(stocksub_list[i])
                    a2 = max(stocksub_list)
                    price2 = None
                    b2 = min(stocksub_list[stocksub_list.index(max(stocksub_list)):])
                    print(a2-b2)
                    
                if s[2] == 'MRNA':
                    stocksub_list1 = st1[st.index(date2):st.index(date3)+1]
                    for i in range(0, len(stocksub_list1)):
                        stocksub_list1[i] = float(stocksub_list1[i])
                    a3 = max(stocksub_list1)
                    price3 = None
                    b3 = min(stocksub_list1[stocksub_list1.index(max(stocksub_list1)):])
                    print(a3-b3)

        elif s[0] == 'FindTrend':
            stocx = [item[0] for item in stocklist]
            stocx1 = [item[1] for item in stocklist]

            stocxx = [item[0] for item in stocklist1]
            stocxx1 = [item[1] for item in stocklist1]

            dat1 = s[2].split('-')
            year3 = dat1[0]
            month3 = dat1[1].lstrip('0')
            day3 = dat1[2].lstrip('0')
            datt2 = month3+'/'+day3+'/'+year3
            
            dat2 = s[3].split('-')
            year4 = dat2[0]
            month4 = dat2[1].lstrip('0')
            day4 = dat2[2].lstrip('0')
            datt3 = month4+'/'+day4+'/'+year4

            if s[1] == 'PFE':
                if datt2 not in stocx:
                    pass
                elif datt3 not in stocx:
                    pass
                else:
                    stock_list = stocx[stocx.index(datt2):stocx.index(datt3)+1]
                    stock_listt = stocx1[stocx.index(datt2):stocx.index(datt3)+1]
                    f = [0] * len(stock_listt)
                    for j in stock_listt:
                        if stock_listt.index(j) < 3:
                            print(stock_list[stock_listt.index(j)] + ' | ' + stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)])
                        elif float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)]) < float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-1]) and float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-1]) > float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-2]) and float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-2]) and float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-2]) > float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-3]) and 1 not in f[stock_listt.index(j)-4:stock_listt.index(j)-1]:
                            f[stock_listt.index(j)] = 1
                            print(stock_list[stock_listt.index(j)] + ' | ' + stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)] + ' | sell')
                        elif float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)]) > float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-1]) and float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-1]) < float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-2]) and float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-2]) and float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-2]) < float(stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)-3]) and 1 not in f[stock_listt.index(j)-4:stock_listt.index(j)-1]:
                            f[stock_listt.index(j)] = 1
                            print(stock_list[stock_listt.index(j)] + ' | ' + stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)] + ' | buy')
                        else:
                            print(stock_list[stock_listt.index(j)] + ' | ' + stock_listt[stock_listt.index(j)])
            if s[1] == 'MRNA':
                if datt2 not in stocxx:
                    pass
                elif datt3 not in stocxx:
                    pass
                else:
                    stock_list1 = stocxx[stocxx.index(datt2):stocxx.index(datt3)+1]
                    stock_listt1 = stocxx1[stocxx.index(datt2):stocxx.index(datt3)+1]
                    f1 = [0] * len(stock_listt1)
                    for m in stock_listt1:
                        if stock_listt1.index(m) < 3:
                            print(stock_list1[stock_listt1.index(m)] + ' | ' + stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)])
                        elif float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)]) < float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-1]) and float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-1]) > float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-2]) and float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-2]) and float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-2]) > float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-3]) and 1 not in f1[stock_listt1.index(m)-4:stock_listt1.index(m)-1]:
                            f1[stock_listt1.index(m)] = 1
                            print(stock_list1[stock_listt1.index(m)] + ' | ' + stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)] + ' | sell')
                        elif float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)]) > float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-1]) and float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-1]) < float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-2]) and float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-2]) and float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-2]) < float(stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)-3]) and 1 not in f1[stock_listt1.index(m)-4:stock_listt1.index(m)-1]:
                            f1[stock_listt1.index(m)] = 1
                            print(stock_list1[stock_listt1.index(m)] + ' | ' + stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)] + ' | buy')
                        else:
                            print(stock_list1[stock_listt1.index(m)] + ' | ' + stock_listt1[stock_listt1.index(m)])

StockMarket()
```

Comment: `I tried arranging it differently but im stuck` this isn't very helpful. What did you try and where did you get stuck? Although a bigger problem is using strings in the first place. It's far safer and *faster* to use the types of the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module like `date` instead. `date`, `time`, `datetime` are binary values, they have no format. Parse the strings into proper types when loading the data instead of trying to deal with strings in the middle of your code

Comment: honestly I dont really understand whats going on here, but if you use datetime.date(), plug in the day, month, and year, you can use the strftime() method to reformat the date in many different ways, very useful

Comment: `s[2]` is *already* in the format you want. The code you posted splits the `YYYY-MM-DD` value and then tries to change the format. You can delete all the "formatting" code and just write `datt2= s[2]`. Are you trying to modify someone else's code without understanding what it does?

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's built-in [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) is a powerful alternative to string-parsing.  Here is a small example:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('31-12-1999', '%d-%m-%Y')

print("0:", type(d))
print("1:", d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
print("2:", d.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))

0: <class 'datetime.datetime'>
1: 1999-12-31
2: 12-31-1999
```

You can calculate days between dates:

```
# days between dates
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-02-29', '%Y-%m-%d')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-03-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
d2 - d1  # datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

And you can add or subtract time deltas from a date:

```
# days before or after a date
print(d1 - datetime.timedelta(days=60))  # 2019-12-31 00:00:00
print(d1 + datetime.timedelta(days=30))  # 2020-03-30 00:00:00
```